# Why don't I get an error Expected 1 argument but got 0?

Tags: typescript

`someFunc` expects a callback with one argument, I pass the callback without arguments, why is the typescript silent? Can someone explain?

```
function someFunc(
  key: string,
  callback: (value: string) => void
) {
  callback(key);
}


someFunc('str', () => {

});
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. You are calling `fucn`, but there is no definition of this function

Comment: @Moti sorry, my mistake, I corrected the example.

Comment: I think, that `()=>void` satisfies constrain of `(anything)=>void` and typescript usually check only for returned value, because its up to your callback if you use that params or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, when you pass a callback function to someFunc without providing the expected argument, the compiler does not raise an error because the callback function is defined as having a single parameter of type string, but the implementation of the callback function itself does not use or require that parameter.

TypeScript allows for the omission of unused function parameters in callback functions. This behavior is intentional to provide flexibility when working with callback-style APIs that may have varying parameter requirements.

In your example, the callback function you provided does not use the value parameter, which is the expected argument. TypeScript does not raise an error because it is valid to define a function with more parameters than are actually used.

If you want to enforce the usage of the value parameter in the callback function, you can enable the noUnusedParameters compiler flag in your TypeScript configuration. This flag will generate a compiler error if any function parameter goes unused.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  }
    }

// Code
function someFunc(
  key: string,
  callback: (value: string) => void
) {
  callback(key);
}

someFunc('str', () => {
  // Error: The 'value' parameter is declared but its value is never read.
});
```

By enabling this flag, TypeScript will raise an error when you pass a callback function that does not use the expected parameter, ensuring that you provide the necessary argument in the callback implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/gp7sl4/typescript_is_not_checking_function_arguments/), it seems to be that the compiler is reading your code and seeing that you aren't doing anything with the parameter provided...
Because of that, it sees the code as "not incorrect", so doesn't step in to tell you there's a problem (yet).

You may want to extend your code a little further, at which point TypeScript might start showing errors about type checking.

I'm personally a fan of separating types

```js
type CallbackType = (value: string) => void;

function someFunc(key: string, callback: CallbackType) {
  callback(key);
}
```

I also tend to tie together types if I know (for example) that `key` should be the *type of the parameter of* `callback`, like so:

```js
function someFunc(key: Parameters<CallbackType>[0], callback: CallbackType) {
  callback(key);
}
```

I think this method comes under the "fail fast" method, if you suddenly changed `CallbackType` to something else (perhaps it takes `string[]` or many more parameters), the compiler errors come to the surface very quickly.
One could argue that having `CallbackType` defined separately also makes the definition of `someFunc` easier to read

In addition (and slightly off-topic), later changing `CallbackType` could affect fewer lines (if you're tracking code in a Git repository) making commits easier to read.